# ViewPager with Parallax-Sticky Header in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Need help in `ViewPager` with parallax-sticky header in `iOS`, 
the way i achieved in `Android` using third party **[library](https://github.com/boxme/ParallaxHeaderViewPager)** (`ParallaxHeaderViewPager`) (example **[video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mam4TFEiWWI)**)

i just want to achieve exact same thing in `iOS`, is there any quick solution / library ( there might be number of libraries for same but couldn't  find it ) for same.

Answer (score 0):

Not a total drop-in, plug and play solution.  But tweaking and customizing this may be a good place to start - https://github.com/gotte/GLOParallaxTabbedProfileViewController